# Disable edit on all the inputs and forms

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage, angular-local-storage

I am working on an application for projects management, the first interface was designed to choose a project from a list and the other interfaces to display edit add... different types of informations to the project selected. 
Our projects have a variable to define if the project is editable or read-only; my question is what is the best way to disable all the inputs in all the different interfaces depending of this variable ?
I can store this variable in the local storage and add to every input something like this :

```
<input ng-class="{disable: readOnly === true}" type="text"....>
```

or for buttons

```
<button ng-hide="readOnly">Submit</button>
```

But I think its an ugly way to do firstly because we are using a global variable with local storage and specially because we didn't anticipate this functionality at the beginning so with this method above I should add code to ALL the inputs, buttons, check box,....

And do we have best practices in this cases to not use local storage ?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say that wrap up your all fields which you wanted to `disable` inside a `fieldset` element, & then just have `ng-disabled="readOnly"` directive on `fieldsset`, so that all the inner fields will get `disabled` once is `readonly` value gets true, by which your all code gets cleaner.

**Markup**

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="readonly">
   ...All fields & button here..
</fieldset>
```

[**Sample Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kgM3WnHakMwXJFEnUuYN?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

**Dear**,

I think using local storage or session storage isn't best practices either. Hence you should take another approach. Though your question isn't very much clear but still i would give you few scenarios to work over it.

1. You could use $rootscope
2. You could use factory or services to pass data from one controller to another

**Thanks & Cheers**